# Prevent information from clearing in fields if user enters wrong info in a field

Tags: javascript, java, php

I'm working on a submission form and if someone gets 1 field wrong, it clears all fields and they have to fill out the form all over again. Anyway to keep the information filled in and they just fix the field that was wrong?

Form
https://shopkatika.com/katika/sellKatikaProduct

Comment: Of course, it's called client-side validation and requires JavaScript code that intercepts the form's submit event. The alternative is to insert all sent data into the `<input>`s using PHP.

Comment: And the other part of the solution (in case client side validation fails or is overridden or isn't possible for some reason) is to re-render the form with all the previous values inside it.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks, I'm a newbie but understood what you meant. Is the javascript code I need to intercept the form submit event the Answer written below?

Comment: No, that answer is about server-side code, PHP. JavaScript happens in the browser and the idea is to validate the entered information before the data is event sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can set back the same form value which you captured from the post request.

So what you have to do is you need to return the same post data appended with error messages.

```
eg: $data=[
'username' => 'abc',
'errormsg'=>'invalid'
]
```

then in HTML file receive that data in a variable

```
<?php $response = functionName(); ?>
```

then in the tag value attribute, you add that

```
<span><?php echo $respose['errormsg'] ?></span>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' value=<?php echo 
$response['username'] ?> />
```

so this will throw error message in a span and the input which they gave will also be there in that.

you can use js to vanish error message after 5secs.